# "class A succeeds class B" means in Scala reference?

Tags: scala

In the Scala 2.8 reference, section 5.3.3 page 69 (77 in the pdf) the following paragraph appear:

> Assume a trait `D` defines some aspect
>   of an instance `x` of type `C` (i.e. `D` is
>   a base class of `C`). Then the actual
>   supertype of `D` in `x` is the compound
>   type consisting of all the base
>   classes in `L(C)` that succeed `D`.

What does the notation `L(C)` means (in the original text it's a calligraphic capital `\ell` like symbol)?

What does the phrase "classes... that **succeed** `D`" means? I'm not familiar with the notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bottom line is, `L(C)` consists of all the base classes (the whole inheritance hierarchy of C, including traits) ordered as a chain, with `Any` at the top, and `C` at the bottom. **Succeeds** `D` means, *is higher in the chain then* `D`.

The longer explanation is that we want to know, for each class, its "parent" -- for implementation purposes and general clarity (it's terribly messy in C++, where unbounded multiple inheritance is allowed). In Java it is simple -- you only have a single direct superclass. However, because of the mixin-class composition in Scala, which is a form of multiple inheritance (from one superclass + possibly several traits), the base classes of any class form a directed acyclic graph. L(C) is the *linearization* of the C's base classes -- starting from the superclass, and adding the traits (and their base classes) such that they form a chain and each class has her own base classes above itself. You can read more about it in Section 6 of [the overview of Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf). It's a nice, comprehensive outline of the feature.

Comment: Actually, I think "succeeds D" means *is **higher** on the chain than D*. The definition says the traits that succeed D are its supertypes with respect to an instance of C.

Comment: no relation to the question, still I'm curious, what's your mother tongue? You refered to class as female "...each class has *her* own..." and I wonder where did it come from. I guess class sounds feminine in your mother tongue.

Comment: @Elazar, it actually *is* feminine in Polish, which is my mother tongue. Funny I'm not consistent throughout the post, though. I must have been thinking in Polish when I was writing the last sentences.

Answer (score 2):

L(C) is [class linearization](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html). Then "succeeds" regards to the position in the result sequence. Linearization is defined in chapter 5.1.2 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).